# Different results between debugging and normal execution c#

Tags: c#, debugging, filesystemwatcher, system.io.file

My program reads a text file and import it into a database. The problem comes when I execute it, files comes every 30 seconds and after the first file arrived, I get the error that the process cannot access the file because it is used by an other process. When I'm debugging, I don't get the error so I can't see what is creating this error. All works well in debug mode...

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("TechDatabase")))
{
    connection.Open();

    try
    {

        List<string> properties = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
        ManureManagementProp newManureProp = new ManureManagementProp
        {
            Water_level = properties.ElementAt(0),
            Wind_speed = properties.ElementAt(1),
            Food_level = properties.ElementAt(2),
            Animal_count = properties.ElementAt(3),
            Number_of_machines = properties.ElementAt(4),
            Machine_id = properties.ElementAt(5),
            Date_time = DateTime.Now
        };


        string query = "INSERT INTO..."; 

        /*Put values in db*/

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        reader.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Updated");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Why use the `using` keyword and then still call `Dispose`?

Comment: `ReadAllLines` doesn't lock the file after its done reading the contents, so it's either code somewhere else in your program or a different application altogether. You can use tools like Resource Monitor to see which programs are locking which files.

Comment: Maybe you are calling this method more than once on parallel process. Or you just open this file in text editor.

Comment: I'm looking up the Resource Monitor but I really don't know what to look up. There's just to many things running in background. Could it be the FileSystemWatcher causing the problem? The Watcher gives the path of the changed file and then the `ReadAllLines` read the file with that path.

I get multiple notifications from the Watcher since it's how it works. First I get a `.Created` and then a `.Changed`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from the FileSystemWatcher. I followed [this](https://philippsen.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/filesystemwatcher-problem-file-is-in-use-by-another-process/) and it works!